# Passing Multiple Joined Tables as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In this application, I have 4 tables (3 object tables and an cross-ref table):

```
create_table "businesses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", limit: 255, null: false
end

create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", limit: 255, null: false
  t.integer "status", limit: 4
end

create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", limit: 255, null: false
  t.integer "business_id", limit: 4, null: false
end

create_table "location_projects", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "project_id", limit: 4
  t.integer "location_id", limit: 4
end

add_index "location_projects", ["project_id"], name: "index_location_projects_on_project_id" using: :btree
add_index "location_projects", ["location_id"], name: "index_location_projects_on_location_id" using: :btree
```

Below are the corresponding models and the associations:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :location_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :location_projects
end

class LocationProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_projects
  has_many :locations, :through => :location_projects
end
```

In a controller, I am running a query as follows:

```
@locations = Location.joins(:projects, :business).where("projects.status <> 9999")
```

And I am setting the repsond_to :json at top of the action and using the following to return JSON back from the action:

```
respond_with @locations
```

When hitting the page, the resulting query is generated (in terminal):

```
SELECT  `locations`.* FROM `locations` INNER JOIN `location_projects` ON `location_projects`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` INNER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `location_projects`.`project_id` INNER JOIN `businesses` ON `businesses`.`id` = `locations`.`business_id` WHERE (projects.status <> 9999)
```

This seems to be working fine.  However, when I call the respond_with @locations, it only serializes the Location record and the Project record, but not the Business record in the JSON that is returned.

Am I missing something here on why the business isn't being returned in the JSON response, but the other two pieces of data are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails won't go deeper than one association when serializing. You have two options: first one is override `as_json` to always return the association on the object you want.

The second and better option, for complex json rendering processes, I suggest you to use a view, jbuilder is there for you: you'll be able to compose the JSON in the way you want. Considering it's plain ruby, you can use stuff like `attributes` method if you don't want to rewrite all attributes for each model manually.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using jbuilder and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to customize your json.